# can we enable logrotate or disable ipamd.logs in EKS

Tags: amazon-eks

We have more than 1500 EKS (kubernetes 1.14), however the disk space under root partition is reaching 100% in less time, reason for this is due to "ipamd.log*" gets created under  /var/log/aws-routed-eni.

Is there any option to apply logrotate ? I checked in the EKS cluster logging, there is no mention of CNI loggings. Any resolution ?